# richTextBox и много-много текста (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем здравствуйте!

Пишу небольшую программку на с# под WinForms и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть длинная строка с текстом, которую. мне нужно засунуть в richTextBox так, чтобы она была одна сплошная и прокручивалась горизонтально, но она постоянно переноситься на другую строку, как только полоса прокрутки достигает определенного размера.
Помогите! надо чтобы это было все в одну! линию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть это не две строки, а одна, добавленная командой:
TextBox.AppendText("много-много-много текста");

Спасибо.

Comment: Все контролы в WinAPI, а следовательно и WinForms, ограничены размером 32767 пикселей.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) написано:

> Всегда переноса текста в RichTextBox. Если не хотите, чтобы затем задайте перенос текста PageWidth на FlowDocument которых превышает ширину RichTextBox. Тем не менее при достижении ширина страницы по-прежнему переноса текста.

Попробуй поиграть с параметром ширины:

```
richTextBox1.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
richTextBox1.Document.PageWidth = 1000;
```

Если это не поможет, то  можно попробовать в DataGridView запихнуть всю информацию. Как я понял у вас текст однотипный.

Comment: Там должно быть свойство WordWrap  или что-то подобное, которое и отвечает за перенос на новую строку если строка не влезла. При очень длинных строках, это тоже может не сработать, и тут уже игры со свойствами не помогут, это в WinAPI.